# excel vba countifs evaluate

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I am getting an error on my evaluate function.

This code is running on a test sheet, so I know that it should give me "1" as answer, but I cannot make it run.

Here are the codes;

```
Check1 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("A3:A" & LastRowE3 & "")
Check2 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("J3:J" & LastRowE3 & "")
Ur_Val = "Production_End"


y = Application.Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & Check1 & ", " & xu_value & ", " & Check2 & ", " & Ur_Val & ")")
```

I know that "y" should be equal to "1", but I cannot get the answer right.

Comment: What is `xu_value` set to?

Comment: Check your variable types.  In your EVALUATE statement you're using the & operator, which would indicate you want to use a string, but since you didn't enclose them in quotes, VBE will default to Variant which may cause problems.  Option Explicit is your friend.

Comment: Paste your full code here otherwise we wouldn't know what are the unknowns.

Comment: Replace `y = Application.Evaluate(...)` with `Debug.Print ...` to output your formula to the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G). If that doesn't look like a legal Excel formula, change your string so that it does. *Then* remove the `Debug.Print` and change it to `y = Application.Evaluate(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first declare your variables:

> `Dim Check1 as String,Check2 as String,Ur_Val as String,xu_value as String`

Then

You want the Address of the ranges not just the range values:

> `Check1 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("A3:A" & LastRowE3 & "").Address(1,1,,1)
>   Check2 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("J3:J" & LastRowE3 & "").Address(1,1,,1)`

And the strings `Ur_Val` and `xu_value` need to be surronded in `"` in the final formula so we need to add them:

> `, """ & xu_value & """,`

So:

```
Dim Check1 as String,Check2 as String,Ur_Val as String,xu_value as String
Dim y as Long
Check1 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("A3:A" & LastRowE3 & "").Address(1,1)
Check2 = Worksheets(Persona).Range("J3:J" & LastRowE3 & "").Address(1,1)
Ur_Val = "Production_End"
xu_value = "SOMETHING_ELSE"


y = Application.Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & Check1 & ", """ & xu_value & """, " & Check2 & ", """ & Ur_Val & """)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never used evaluate in vba for long formulas like this. I'll keep in mind your suggestions. This worked well.